# Any way or application to make text appear and stay on top of all windows open in Windows?

Tags: windows, presentations

I want to make it so that there is the text "Display 1" at the top right corner of the secondary display on my computer regardless of the number of applications I have open. No matter how I move the windows open or drag them around, the text "Display 1" will always be there. Though I can customize the text to show some other text.

Is there any application that allows me to do this? I want to use it in a presentation I want to give involving multiple applications running.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest but perhaps not the most visually elegant is to just open Notepad(or any text box), write "Display 1", (increase font size if need to) and then use any tool that allows you to pin a window as "Always on top", for example a very basic "Window On Top" tool from http://www.skybn.com/.

Some display drivers also have such functionality built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rainmeter](http://rainmeter.net/cms/), though it's primary function is not that, you can edit an skin, have custom text, that is on top of all windows and you can click through it.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://www.hottnotes.com/) is a small powerful tool called hottnotes will help you sure.

You can change colors , size , transparency & many more .. It will do lot for you too..

[image]

[image]